# Why must the probability of an event be between 0 and 1?

Tags: probability

Let me put it in this way:

Define A= Head turned up, B= Tail turned up

If I toss a coin, it is natural to say that the probability of A and B is $P(A)=P(B)=\frac{1}{2}$.

Why we can't assign, let's  say, 0.6 to the probability of each events? That is, $P(A)=P(B)=0.6$

We can't do this because $P(A)+P(B)>1$ but why it must be 1?

Is there a fundamental reason that the probability of an event must be some number between $0$ and $1$? Or we adopted this convention that 1 as a scale?

Comment: Yes: it represents a percentage.

Comment: @Bernard What? No. A percentage is a way to represent a proportion. And in any case that says nothing about probabilities.

Comment: You can look at  one definition of probability: $p=\frac{\text{Number of favorable events (F)}}{\text{Number of all possible events (S)}}$ It is obvious that $0\leq p \leq 1$ since $F \subseteq S$

Comment: You could assign values to events in a different way, but *probability* has a meaning intended to reflect uncertainty about whether a event will occur or not.  Hence the extremes of $0$ and $1$ are reflective of the potential that the event *never* occurs or *always* occurs.  Mathematically the values $0$ and $1$ make the statements of "laws of probability" elegant, so perhaps your attention should be directed to some of these.

Comment: @hardmath good response, you could make that an answer...

Comment: @Joffan:  I will wait to see if the OP clarifies in some way that this is the kind of answer they are looking for.  I'm having some doubt about the level of math studies that motivated the Question.

Comment: @Joffan: The percentage of chance the event be realised. This is the historical origin (the ratio of favourable cases).

Comment: @Bernard A reference to "ratio" would have been far more appropriate - with your supporting text. Talking about percentage just implies that the range should be 0 to 100 and generates confusion.

Comment: Because axioms ... as @hardmath already said,  the concept is made this way in order to be elegant and to reflect our intuitive understanding of probability. You can choose other values, but you are going to run into a lot of problems in order to make sure everything is consistent

Answer (score 1):

For any event $A$, a certain event $B$, and an impossible event $C$, where $A$, $B$ and $C$ are all independent, we need $A$ and $B$ happening to be as probable as $B$, $B$ and $C$ happening to be as probable as $C$, and $A$ and $C$ happening to be as probable as $C$. Written out with the definition of independence, this means that:

$$P(AB) = P(A)P(B) = P(A)$$
$$P(BC) = P(B)P(C) = P(C)$$
$$P(AC) = P(A)P(C) = P(C)$$

The events $A$ and $C$ are also disjoint ($C$ won't happen whenever $A$ happens because $C$ *can't* happen), and since we need the probability of either happening to equal the probability of just $A$ happening, we need:
$$P(A \cup C) = P(A) + P(C) = P(A)$$

These are all true only if $P(B) = 1$ and $P(C) = 0$. Put differently, in order for independence to distribute through probabilities, we need certainty to correspond with the multiplicative identity 1 and impossibility to correspond with the additive identity 0. Formally, this is true in any probability space where the events form a field.

*Edit: better justification for impossibility being 0*

Comment: This would be fixed by putting scale factors in so it is not really a satisfactory answer.

Comment: @Ian: I don't believe so. Let $x$ represent certainty instead of 1. Let $A$ and $B$ be certain events that are independent (for instance, $A$ is drawing a red ball from a trashcan of red balls, $B$ is drawing a blue ball from a trashcan of blue balls). Then $P(AB) = P(A)P(B) = x^2$, which is more or less than certain if $x \neq 1$. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, you fix it by defining independence as $P(AB)=P(A)P(B)/x$ in the first place. This is easy to see, just replace each probability in the usual formalism by $x$ times itself. It is just annoying to deal with this normalization constant all the time.

Comment: I see. I think this is morally equivalent to setting up a field, but I see that in principle you can model the standard (more convenient) treatment without direct reference to the number 1.

Answer (score 1):

Each of the several definitions of "probability" implies that the probability of disjoint events must sum to less than $1$.

If you are tossing a fair coin then by definition of "fair" each of the two possibilities is equally likely. Then the probability of $H$ is 
$$
\frac{\text{number of possible outcomes with } H}{\text{number of possible outcomes}} = \frac{1}{2}.
$$

If you have a real coin and you don't know whether or not it's fair then you toss it many times to figure out the probability using that kind of fraction, where you use the total number of heads seen for the numerator and the total number of tosses as the denominator. That might come out to be $0.6$. Since you always see a tail when you don't see a head, that must have happened $40\%$ of the time.

Either definition must always result in a fraction between $0$ and $1$. In either case the probability will be $0$ if the numerator event never happens and $1$ if it always happens.

Answer (score 1):

One advantage to having outcome probabilities for a (discrete) sample space sum to $1$, is that then the probability of an outcome (or event) is the same as the (expected or long-term) relative frequency of the outcome (or event).

For instance in your coin example, having $P(H)=P(T)=0.6$ may be well and good for some purposes; but still you would get heads and tails each with a relative frequency of $0.5$